# Начал получить ошибку при создание нового проекта в nuxt

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, nuxt.js

Я не использую `python`, просто хочу установить новый проект

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Saq\blackList\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 3
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - executable path is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - executable path is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - executable path is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python311-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python311-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python311-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python311-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python310-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python310-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python310-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is ""
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - version is  - should be >=3.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - THIS VERSION OF PYTHON IS NOT SUPPORTED
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe" could not be run
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Saq\blackList\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:306:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at PythonFinder.findPython (C:\Saq\blackList\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:164:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async configure (C:\Saq\blackList\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:23:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async run (C:\Saq\blackList\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js:81:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19045
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Saq\\blackList\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Saq\blackList\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Saq\npm-cache\_logs\2024-02-15T14_03_39_760Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Ну оно хочет любой питон начиная от версии 3.6.0, поставьте какой-нибудь питон. Только не самый последний 3.12, с ним ещё не всё совместимо.